# Problem with nodejs query $in and null value

Tags: node.js, mongodb

in native mongodb request, we can check if a field exist or not like this :
exemple for docs :

```
[{name:"test1",profil:"profilA"};{name:"test2"};{name:"test3",profil:"profilB"}]
```

if we want to check all doc who match with "profilA" and when profil unexist we can make :

```
db.getCollection('col').find({"profil":{"$in":[null,"profilA"]}})
```

in mongodDb native shell, the result is perfect :

```
[{name:"test1",profil:"profilA"},{name:"test2"}]
```

In fact, null value match all doc whithout "profil" field.

In nodejs with mongodb driver, the result is not the same :

```
[{name:"test1",profil:"profilA"}]
```

The null value is not matching so...

Is it a bug with nodejs driver ?

Thank's a lot for helps...

JP

Comment: Please provide the code from your node.js driver

Comment: I just use MongoDB Node.JS Driver (officiel MongoDb driver) version 2.2.31 with simple nodejs app. Perhaps last version is better (3.1.13) ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for this question, in fact all works perfectly. It was due to another personnal error...